# typo3 tt_products language file

Tags: typo3

I have configured in TS setup: markerFile = path to file de.locallang_marker.xlf

```
      <trans-unit id="p_category" resname="p_category" approved="yes">
        <source>Category</source>
        <target state="final">Kategorie</target>
      </trans-unit>
```

How do I use this now in the template?
Since tt_products uses "old style templates" with markers, the markers used in the template are mainly used to fetch data from the DB like ###CATEGORY_TITLE###. But I havn't seen anywhere in the example templates markers to get some translated texts!

Help appreciated

Regards
Karl-Heinz

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:
I used:
`###p_category###`
but it must be in capital letters
`###P_CATEGORY###`